# Cookies are not passed in chrome when a site A is loaded in an iframe in site B, so login is not happening

Tags: google-chrome, kubernetes, nginx, cookies

We are trying to access `A` website in `B` client website using Iframe. As per suggestions we enabled the below conf in nginx in our source server (its a kubernets, where I configure in nginx ingress yml file..

```
add_header Set-Cookie $sent_http_set_cookie; 
add_header Set-Cookie "$sent_http_set_cookie; SameSite=None; secure" always;
```

Now whenever I tried to login its not login and coming back to login page.(I accessed `B.com`). This happens only in Chrome.. Firefox I am successfully able to login.. Is there anything I need to do extra setting in NGINX for chrome. I didt have access to code for Server `A`.

I see a proxy_cookie_path in nginx, but I am not sure how can I add that ti nginx.

Comment: Web-browsers are slowly chipping-away at third-party cookies. This isn't a server-side thing. You could try using Storage Access API, though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_Access_API

Comment: How can I use that.. I don't have control over the code for `A` that is loaded in iframe

Comment: Unless you can contact the owners of `A` and tell them to update their website to no-longer depend on third-party cookies (such as by using browser-vendor-approved systems like the aforementioned _Storage Access API_) then there's nothing you can do about it, as that's all by-design.

Comment: ...though there is a possible workaround, such as using a "sign-in helper" program, which is basically a `localhost`-only HTTP webserver that responds to `fetch( 'http://localhost:1234/etc' )` requests from website `B` with details needed to access website `A` all in the browser - but this only works in controlled environments (like internal company networks where software can be deployed via Group Policy, or Kiosk computers) - this approach doesn't work at all on the wider public Internet for what should be obvious reasons.